# Why did Jon Snow go beyond the wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We in see in end of *Game of Thrones* that Jon Snow has to go to Castle Black as part of his punishment for killing Daenerys. But then he goes with the wildlings beyond the wall. Why did he go with them and not stay at Castle Black?

Comment: @NogShine is not where and why different questions?

Comment: @AnkitSharma the answer there also answers this question though.

Comment: @JAD for me asnwer don't make question duplicate question do

Comment: @AnkitSharma for me the questions being similar (not 100% duplicate) **and** the answer being relevant tips the scales. But hey, it's a vote after all.

Comment: @JAD oops my bad that question did ask why too